# Django Group Permission Check in Template

Tags: python, django

I want to check group have permission in template for loop.

My Context Processors

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,Group,Permission
from django.db.models import Q
def users(request):
    users = User.objects.filter(is_active=1).exclude(id=request.user.id)
    groups = Group.objects.exclude(Q(name='customer') | Q(name='vendor') | Q(name='labour'))
    permissions = Permission.objects.all()

    return {
        'all_users': users,
        'all_groups' : groups,
        'permissions' : permissions
    }
```

My template

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Permission</th>
        <th>Content Type</th>
        <th>Access Group</th>
    </tr>
    {% for permission in permissions %}
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td>
            {{permission.name}}
            <input type="hidden" name="permission_{{permission.id}}" />
        </td>
        <td>
            {{permission.content_type.app_label}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {% for group in all_groups %}
                <span class="checkboxes fln">
                    <span class="checkbox">
                        <small class="single checkNo">                                          
                            <input type="checkbox" name="group_{{group.id}}_permission_{{permission.id}}"/>
                        </small>
                        <b>{{group.name}}</b>
                    </span>
                </span>
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

If group have permission , I want to change this line.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group_{{group.id}}_permission_{{permission.id}}" {%if 'condition'  %} checked="checked" {% endif %}/>
```

How can I check group have that permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group permissions are in, well, permissions:

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.permissions)

> **permissions**
>
> Many-to-many field to Permission:

So you could just do:

```
{% if permission in group.permissions.all  %} checked="checked" {% endif %}
```

Comment: No luck , {% if permission in group.permissions %} x {% else %} y {% endif %}. result is y. but , my auth_group_permissions table have this permission for this group.