# Django Group permission how to print it in template

Tags: python, django

if the customer sign in and he has permission to see the data that the admin has given to him, he will see the data after he sign in, but if the admin doesn't give him permission, this message will appear **You are not authorized to view this page**

in my case no matter what the permission given the admin this message always appears **You are not authorized to view this page**

```
from .decorators import unathenticated_user, allowed_users,staff_only
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
@staff_only

def adminpage(request):
    return render(request, 'Homepage/adminsite.html')
def loginpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            username = request.POST['username']
            request.session['username'] = username
            return redirect('adminpage')
        else:

            return render(request, 'Homepage/adminlogin.html')

    return render(request, 'Homepage/adminlogin.html')
```

this is my decorators.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect




def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_staff:
            return redirect('adminpage')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_func



def allowed_users(allowed_roles=None):
    if allowed_roles is None:
        allowed_roles = []
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                return redirect('adminpage')
            if group in allowed_roles:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorized to view this page')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator

def staff_only(view_func):
    def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = None
        if request.user.groups.exists():
            group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

        if group == 'registrar':
            return redirect('adminpage')

        if group == 'admin':
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_function
```

this is my admin site (permission)

[image]

this is my login looks like

[image]

after I sign in (UPDATED ERROR)

[image]

thanks in advance

this is my html

**NOTE** I dont know if this html is working. because of my logic error, I am sorry for that, I just want to print the permissions that admin given to the customer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if request.user|group:"registrar" %}
    <p>User belongs to my group</p>
{% else %}
    <p>User does not belong to my group</p>
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

this is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
       path('adminpage/', Homepage.views.adminpage, name='adminpage'),
       path('loginpage/', Homepage.views.loginpage, name='loginpage'),
  ]
```

this is the error in my html

if you have any question, I am happy to provide an answer inorder to answer this question[image]

Comment: Does this line of code printed on your terminal? `print('working', allowed_roles)`. Make sure that you've changed the model and save it properly. There is one more I feel it's not true is that you check this `if group in allowed_roles:` but you didn't assign value for `group` variable.

Comment: Can you also post the html template you are using?

Comment: okay, please wait

Comment: please see the update question.

Comment: @Toan Quoc Ho can you show me you answer ? please

Comment: I couldn't give an answer because the question is lacking information and there are a couple things which aren't match with the question. For example, you've said that the page always return `You are not authorized to view this page`. But `allowed_users` has never been called so how it can happen. Could you also please provide your urls.py file? Which contain the route from `/adminpage/` to `adminpage` view.

Comment: please check my update question

Comment: I also update the error

Comment: `def staff_only(view_func):
    return wrapper_function`

This function has missing else case.

Comment: @sonus21 can you post your answer? So if your ever your answer is correct, I will mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking how to print but as obvious you have some other problems. The other answer has solved the problem on your `staff_only` decorator. Since you did not cover every case your decorator where returning None. It has been corrected by the other user but to make all in one place i will give detail too.

```py
def staff_only(view_func):
    def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = None
        if request.user.groups.exists():
            groups = list(request.user.groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True))

        if 'admin' in groups or 'registrar' in groups:
            """I assume that registrar is also staff"""
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

        return redirect("loginpage")

    return wrapper_function
```

In your decorator you were only taking users first group and compare it's name. However users may have multiple groups. Thus you need to check the whole list. My solution above gets all groups in a list and check if it fits the conditions and do continue to the view or redirect.

In your template you are using not existing template filter `group`.

You may change it as following:

```html
<body>
{% for group in request.user.groups.all %}
    {% if group.name == 'registrar' %}
        <p>User belongs to my group</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

If you want to print all groups you may do the following.

```html
<body>
<ul>
{% for group in request.user.groups.all %}
    <li>{{group.name}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
```

However the best way of checking if user has a group in template is creating a template filter for that purpose. You can check [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

```
@register.filter(name='has_group')
def has_group(user, group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

in your template:

```
<body>
{% if request.user|has_group:"registrar" %}
    <p>User belongs to my group</p>
{% else %}
    <p>User does not belong to my group</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
```

Comment: When I apply your answer mr @scriptmonster and sign in the user that have a permission of registrar, I encounter error """ redirected you too many times. """"

Comment: You are getting redirect error due to redirection to same page. I have taken that part from your code. Does registrar group has permission to see adminpage? If so the code staff_only decorator would be changing a little. Please check my update.

Comment: @İsmailTahaAYKAÇ what is the changes  if i have multiple group?

Comment: @justin for printing or checking?

Comment: @İsmailTahaAYKAÇ for checking. i would like to apply this answer of yours in my code, but in my case i have multiple group permission

Comment: You may create a template filter similar to mine. Let’s say you define a template tag named has_groups, and you pass group names in the template separated with comma. In your code you will split them and develop the logic. That’s the first solution come to my mind.

Comment: @İsmailTahaAYKAÇ please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62188595/django-multiple-group-permission

Answer (score 2):

```
def staff_only(view_func):
    def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = None
        if request.user.groups.exists():
            group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
        if group == 'registrar':
            return redirect('adminpage')

        if group == 'admin':
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return redirect("loginpage")

    return wrapper_function
```

This function is missing case when a user does not have required groups, in this case, either we should either redirect a user to login page send to another page or display like "You don't have access to this page"

Comment: how do I print the group permission in the html?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795981/django-group-permission-check-in-template