# Django multiple group permission

Tags: python, django

I have similar question about **group permission** but in my case i have **multiple group permission**

what should i do in my **decorator.py** that if the user have permission for registrar it will go to registrar page and if the user have a permission for mis it go to mis page, same goes for the accounting

[Django Group permission how to print it in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60798441/django-group-permission-how-to-print-it-in-template/61987041?noredirect=1#comment109985923_61987041)

This is my views.py

```
@staff_only
@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
def registrar_adminpage(request):
     #this is for group permission 'Registrar'
    return render(request, 'Homepage/Registrar_adminsite.html'})

@staff_only
@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
def mis_adminpage(request):
     #this is for group permission 'MIS'
    return render(request, 'Homepage/mis_adminsite.html'})

@staff_only
@login_required(login_url='loginpage')
def accounting_adminpage(request):
     #this is for group permission 'Accounting'
    return render(request, 'Homepage/accounting_adminsite.html'})
```

my decorators.py

```
def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_staff:

            return redirect('registrar_adminpage')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_func

def allowed_users(allowed_roles=None):
    if allowed_roles is None:
        allowed_roles = []
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
            if group in allowed_roles:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorized to view this page')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator


def staff_only(view_func):
    def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        groups = None
        if request.user.groups.exists():
            groups = list(request.user.groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True))
        if 'registrar' in groups:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if 'mis' in groups:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if 'accounting' in groups:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return redirect("registrar_adminpage")

    return wrapper_function
```

update this is the name of my group permission and specific user (staff)

[image]

Comment: better to use `user_pass_test` decorator

Comment: user_pass_test ? what do you mean by that?

Comment: `user_pass_test` decorator that provide by django and you will check whatever base on user or request it allowed user or not search it how to implement `user_pass_test` decorator

Comment: can you please give an example using my code?

Comment: yes i give answer

Comment: nice, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i can see you have tried to create a decorator of yours. However there are some problems in the logic;

```py
from functools import wraps

def groups_only(*groups):
    def inner(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func)
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=groups).exists():
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorized to view this page')
        return wrapper_func
    return inner
```

You may use your new decorator as follows:

```py
@groups_only('Admin', 'Registrar')
def registrar_adminpage(request):
     #this is for group permission 'Registrar'
    return render(request, 'Homepage/Registrar_adminsite.html'})
```

The other solution is using `user_pass_test` decorator as it is mentioned in the comments. However it would be hard to pass user groups dynamically for that scenario. You will be coding a new test function for each cases.

In order to debug the problems on permission names you can change the decorator as following:

```py
from functools import wraps

def groups_only(*groups):
    def inner(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func)
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            print('Allowed User Groups:', ','.join(groups))
            print('Users Current Groups:', ','.join(list(request.user.groups.all().values_list('name', flat=True))))
            if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=groups).exists():
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorized to view this page')
        return wrapper_func
    return inner
```

While running this code you will be seeing the allowed groups and users groups printed on the runserver stdout. You may check if there is something wrong.

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax i got this error from decorators.py

Comment: fixed, you may test again.

Comment: it keep saying "" You are not authorized to view this page "" event the user have permission

Comment: Please check that again.

Comment: i got an error, when the user have permission of 'admin' the user still go to the registrar page

Comment: my two user is staff

Comment: The name of the permissions needs to be exactly the same with case sensitive manner. please add print statements to debug the issue. I will add how you coulde debug in my answer.

Comment: when i tried to copy your updated answer and sign in the accounting Allowed User Groups: registrar
Users Current Groups: accounting

Comment: adn for registrar user i receive this Allowed User Groups: registrar
Users Current Groups: registrar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215282/discussion-between-smail-taha-aykac-and-justin).

Answer (score 0):

define decorator in
@decorators.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib.auth.models     import Group

def check_is_registrar(func): # refistrar

    def check_is_user_group(user):
        ''' Check User in which Group Wrapper function'''
        return user.groups.filter(name='registrar').exists()   

    pass_test = user_passes_test(check_is_user_group)
    return pass_test(func)

def check_is_mis(func): # mis

    def check_is_user_group(user):
        ''' Check User in which Group Wrapper function'''
        return user.groups.filter(name='mis').exists()   

    pass_test = user_passes_test(check_is_user_group)
    return pass_test(func)

def check_is_accounting(func): # accounting

    def check_is_user_group(user):
        ''' Check User in which Group Wrapper function'''
        return user.groups.filter(name='accounting').exists()   

    pass_test = user_passes_test(check_is_user_group)
    return pass_test(func)
```

define `LOGIN_URL='loginpage'` in settings.py
@views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators        import method_decorator

@method_decorator([login_required,check_is_registrar],name='dispatch')
def registrar_adminpage(request):
     #this is for group permission 'Registrar'
    return render(request, 'Homepage/Registrar_adminsite.html'})

@method_decorator([login_required,check_is_mis],name='dispatch')
def mis_adminpage(request):
     #this is for group permission 'MIS'
    return render(request, 'Homepage/mis_adminsite.html'})


@method_decorator([login_required,check_is_accounting],name='dispatch')
def accounting_adminpage(request):
     #this is for group permission 'Accounting'
    return render(request, 'Homepage/accounting_adminsite.html'})
```

You may also reduce one decorator function

```
def check_is(func,group_name=None): # refistrar

    if group_name:
        def check_is_user_group(user):
            ''' Check User in which Group Wrapper function'''
            return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()   

    pass_test = user_passes_test(check_is_user_group)
    return pass_test(func)
```

and be like

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators        import method_decorator
from decorators import check_in

@method_decorator([login_required,check_is(group_name='registrar')],name='dispatch')
def registrar_adminpage(request):
     #this is for group permission 'Registrar'
    return render(request, 'Homepage/Registrar_adminsite.html'})
```

use passing difference group name in parameter of decorator
try this and let me know

Comment: NameError: name 'check_is' is not defined

Comment: you should import decorator  in views.py

Comment: from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator, check_is

Comment: how do i import it?

Comment: import in `view.py` like `from decorators import check_is`